# Keep the choice made as constant in a shiny widget that exists inside a dynamic tabsetPanel()

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to create a `shiny` app in which the user displays or not a secret tab. The issue is that I want the `radioButtons()` inside the main panel to keep the choice that I give to it if I change it and return to the selected one if I choose to hide or display the secret tab.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("displaySecretTab", "Display Secret Tab", choices = c("Yes", "No"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tabsets")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tabsets<-renderUI({
    if(input$displaySecretTab=="Yes"){
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabs",
        tabPanel("tab 1",
                 radioButtons("ftype", "Choose file type", choices = c("CSV" = "csv", "Excel (.xlsx)" = "xlsx", "Excel (.xls)" = "xls"), selected = "csv")),
        tabPanel("secret"))
      
    }
    else{
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabs",
        tabPanel("tab 1",
                 radioButtons("ftype", "Choose file type", choices = c("CSV" = "csv", "Excel (.xlsx)" = "xlsx", "Excel (.xls)" = "xls"), selected = "csv")),
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: firmo23> See also `showTab`/`hideTab`, if you don't want to loose the contents of the secret tab, if there's any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `insertTab`/`removeTab`:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("displaySecretTab", "Display Secret Tab", choices = c("Yes", "No"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id="tabs",
        tabPanel("tab 1",
                 radioButtons("ftype", "Choose file type", choices = c("CSV" = "csv", "Excel (.xlsx)" = "xlsx", "Excel (.xls)" = "xls"), selected = "csv")),
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$displaySecretTab, {
    if(input$displaySecretTab=="Yes"){
      insertTab(
        "tabs",
        tabPanel("secret")
      )
    } else {
      removeTab("tabs", "secret")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```